# Angular library that allows to sort ngRepeat items using absolute positioning

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drag-and-drop

I'm looking for an library that will allow to sort items with drag&drop events.

Unfortunately for me most of the libraries use HTML5 DragAndDrop events with required relative position, but my elements position could be only static (those elements stored in svg foreignobject and it should be scalable, that's why relative position is not possible).

So I suppose it could be implemented when user drag an element it should copy it into the DOM with absolute position. Also I need to support placeholder and different ngRepeat containers.

Code which I got so far.

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app')
    .directive('dtDraggableResource', draggableResourceDirective);

  function draggableResourceDirective($document) {

    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, element, attr) {
        var dragElement;
        var dragX, dragY;

        element.on('mousedown', function(event) {

          if(!dragElement) {
            var offset = element[0].getBoundingClientRect();
            dragX = offset.left;
            dragY = offset.top;
            dragElement = element[0].cloneNode(true);
            dragElement.className += ' dragged-element noselect';
            dragElement.style.position = 'absolute';
            dragElement.style.opacity = '0.9';
            dragElement.style.visibility = 'visible';
            dragElement.style.left = offset.left  + 'px';
            dragElement.style.top = offset.top + 'px';
            dragElement.style.width = element[0].offsetWidth + 'px';
            dragElement.style['z-index'] = 2500;

            element.css('display', 'none');
            angular.element(document.body).append(dragElement);
          }

          $document.on('mousemove', mousemove);
          $document.on('mouseup', mouseup);
        });

        function mousemove(event) {
          dragX += event.originalEvent.movementX;
          dragY += event.originalEvent.movementY;
          dragElement.style.left = dragX + 'px';
          dragElement.style.top = dragY + 'px';
        }

        function mouseup() {
          dragElement.remove();
          dragElement = null;

          element.css('display', 'block');
          $document.off('mousemove', mousemove);
          $document.off('mouseup', mouseup);
        }
      }
    }
  }

})();
```

but it seems to much work need to be done, probably should be out-of-box solutions or if anyone know drag&drop reorder tutorial would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

I found an library https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable that has an fallback from HTML5 and appendToBody property. Worked for me.